# When clicked on li items from list how to append clicked item in separate div and remaining list item in different div tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `li` list items. When I click on any one `li` item it should get appended or displayed to one div tag and the remaining list items at the sam time  should get appended in other div tag using jQuery.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.main-menu li', function() {
  $('.sidenav').append($('.topnav')[0].innerHTML);
  $('.topnav').empty();
  $(this).remove()
});
```

```html
<div class="topnav"></div>
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="acc">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
         List One
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subnav">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          List Two
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-list">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          List Three
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="sidenav"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Firstly, you can't append an `li` to a `div`, only another `ul`. Secondly it's not at all clear what you're trying to do. The append the `li` to the `div` part is clear, but the rest doesn't make much sense. Could you please edit the question to give more detail.

Comment: Could you please re-write your question to be clearer - use some punctuation because your sentence is just one big garbled lump of text and it's very hard to comprehend. Also a specific example of your problem would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson suppose i have  li list items so when i click on on that perticular item it should get save or append in one div tag and at the same time only remaining list items <li></li> append to other div tag

Comment: ok but as mentioned already you cannot append an `<li>` to a `<div>`. So you need a `<ul>` within the div before you begin, and append the items to that instead. Also what have you tried so far? The code shown in the question is not even close to achieving what you want - in fact it almost does the opposite. This suggest you haven't researched this very much, if at all. We're here to help you, but please make some effort yourself as well. If there's something specific which you don't understand how to code it, please tell us the actual problem rather than simply stating your requirements.

Comment: Which `div` tags? Please be specific

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood correctly what you expected. As mentionned before, if you want to append li to your div, you need a parent ul on top.

As suggested, here is a snippet :

```js
$('.main-menu li').on('click', function(_click) {
  var $selectedLi = $(_click.currentTarget);
  $('.topnav ul').append($selectedLi.clone());
  $selectedLi.remove();
  $('.sidenav ul').append($('.main-menu ul').clone());
  $('.main-menu ul').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="acc">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
         List One
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subnav">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          List Two
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-list">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          List Three
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="sidenav">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why using jsfiddle ? Use a runnable snippet instead.

Comment: Actually, this is not what the OP wants to achieve, in this code the items can be clicked only once and the initial `ul` is destructed after the click.

Comment: Well, sorry if I misunderstood but it's quite difficult to get what is expected from the OP :-/
If the goal is to "copy" elements, then I can edit the snippet to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't append `li` elements to `div`, they can just be appended to a list element.

What you need to do is to get the `text` of the `li` elements and append it to the `divs`, and use `$('.main-menu li').not($(this))` to get other `li` elements, where `$(this)` is the clicked `li` element.

This is how should be your code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.main-menu li', function() {
  $('.sidenav').text($(this).text());
  $('.topnav').empty();
  $('.main-menu li').not($(this)).each(function(i) {
    $('.topnav').append($('.main-menu li').not($(this))[i].textContent);
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.main-menu li', function() {
  $('.sidenav').text($(this).text());
  $('.topnav').empty();
  $('.main-menu li').not($(this)).each(function(i) {
    $('.topnav').append($('.main-menu li').not($(this))[i].textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav"></div>
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="acc">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
         List One
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subnav">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          List Two
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-list">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
          List Three
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="sidenav"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```